# Is there any way to detect a keypress that is executed programmatically?

Tags: python, python-keyboard

I want to detect if a keypress was executed programmatically (not by user's physical press). Is there any way to do this?

```
import mouse
import keyboard
import time


keyboard.press("a")

if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
    print ("pressed")
```

I assume 'is_pressed' in the code above only detects actual input from user hence it wouldn't show print ("pressed"). All I could come up with to solve this is the code below which works just fine for my intention but I want to know if there's a better optimized way.

```
import mouse
import keyboard
import time
    
    
keyboard.press("a")
keyboard_a = True

keyboard.press("b")
keyboard_b = True
    
if keyboard_a:
    print ("a pressed")

if keyboard_b:
    print ("b pressed")
```

Comment: Do you mean - you want to detect if a keypress event was issued from some code pushing a key-press event, and not from a keyboard device?

Comment: Oh, hold on. You think `print("pressed")` issues key-press events to the console to write the word `pressed`, is that it?

Comment: @JimmyNJ the first one, the way to detect if the key press event is triggered progammatically

Comment: To be clear, it is *your own code* that is emitting the programmatic key-presses that you want to detect? You should change that code, not the code that handles the key-press events. It is very strange for you to emit programmatic key-presses from the same program that is listening for those key-presses; there are much better ways for a program to send data to another part of the same program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to distinguish between key press events that are triggered programmatically and those that are triggered by user input. The same is true for `readchar`, `msvcrt`, or `keyboard` libraries.

So, the library provides a way to detect and respond to key press events, regardless of their origin. Hence, your approach with a flag is good.

I don't know your precise aim, but maybe you would prefer to use `send` and a register event like this

```
import keyboard
import threading

is_programmatic = False

# Define a function to be called when a specific key is pressed
def on_key_press(keyEvent):
    global is_programmatic

    if keyEvent.name == 'a':
        if is_programmatic:
            print("Key press event triggered programmatically")
        else:
            print("Key press event triggered by user input")
    
        is_programmatic = False

# Register listener
keyboard.on_press(on_key_press)

# Start keyboard listener
keyboard.wait()

# or start a thread with the listener (you may want to sleep some seconds to wait the thread)
thread = threading.Thread(target=keyboard.wait)
thread.start()
```

and to issue the event

```
is_programmatic = True
keyboard.send("a")
```

Comment: the code you provided doesnt work for some reason.

Comment: @kerz - provide an error message so the author can try to help.

Comment: theres no error message it just keeps idling. i think its because the 'key' argument in on_key_press takes more than just a key input. i tried print (key) and it prints'KeyboardEvent(a down)', not just 'a'

Comment: still haven't figured how to fix this

Comment: keyboard.wait() function is a blocking function that waits for keyboard events indefinitely the implementation depend on what you have to do. I updated the code with the threaded version. There was also a bug since the variable catched is an event and not the key itself

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list and store pressed keys in that list. You can find if a key is pressed by searching that list.

```
import keyboard

key_pressed = []

keyboard.press("a")
key_pressed.append("a")

keyboard.press("b")
key_pressed.append("b")

keyboard.press("c")
key_pressed.append("c")

#check if a specific key is pressed
if "a" in key_pressed:
    print ("a pressed")
```

Print all pressed keys:

```
for key in key_pressed:
    print(key,'pressed')
```

Print the last pressed key:

```
print(key_pressed[-1])
```

You can also create a class to make it easier to use:

```
import keyboard
class CustomKeyboard():
    def __init__(self):
    self.pressed_keys = []

def press(self, key):
    keyboard.press(key)
    self.pressed_keys.append(key)

def is_pressed_programmatically(self, key):
    if key in self.pressed_keys:
        return True
    return False
```

Then use it like this:

```
kb = CustomKeyboard()

kb.press('a')
kb.press('b')

print("did a pressed programmatically?:")
print(kb.is_pressed_programmatically('a'))

print("did z pressed programmatically?:")
print(kb.is_pressed_programmatically('z'))
```

and here is the output:

> is a pressed programmatically?: True
>
> is z pressed programmatically?: False

Comment: i also thought of this as well but just curious if theres a better way

Comment: @kerz As I know there is not a built-in function in keyboard library. You may also create a class to handle this functionality in a more beautiful way. I will edit my answer and show you how.